# Epson SDK issue

Tags: android, printing, sdk, epson

I am using the EPSON SDK for the thermal printer. It works in 64 bit mobile/tablet. But I got the issue in the 32-bit tablet. The app gets the following crash. In-app I had the libepos2 file in the following which is inside the JNI libs **("armeabi", "arm64-v8a", "x86")**.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.sample.printer-1/lib/x86/libepos2.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40